# When did the Kin/Gin Brothers get their Nine-Tails power?

Tags: naruto

Now I'm rather confused. The timeline doesn't add up to me. I was hoping someone to shed some light.

So here's how the events seemingly happened.

1. The hidden cloud had, for a period, attempted to capture the nine-tails.
2. As a result, the nine-tails ate the Kin/Gin Brothers.
3. To survive, they ate the flesh from his stomach.
4. The nine-tails spit them out, and they had his chakra when they were expelled.

That's all fine, but **it doesn't add up**.

- It was said that between the five great villages, the Hidden Leaf was the first.
- It was also said that after Madara's and Hashirama's battle, the nine-tails was sealed inside Hashirama's wife, Mito.
- Shortly before Mito died, the nine-tails was transferred to Kushina.
- During the short nine-tails attack on the village (after being freed from Kushina), the nine-tails was sealed again, inside of Naruto.

Now, we also know that the Kin/Gin brothers were at the same time as the second Hokage, Tobirama. Given that they were the ones who killed him.

**When did they have time to get swallowed up by the nine-tails?**. The Hidden Cloud village didn't exist before Konoha did, so it can't be *before* Madara's and Hashirama's battle, and right after that, the nine-tails was in constant Leaf possession.

So when? When did the cloud try to get the nine-tails?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this Naruto Wiki page](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kurama#Background) (second and third paragraphs), **the brothers were swallowed by Kurama *before* the battle between Hashirama and Madara took place** (the battle after Madara's desertion from Konoha, when he used the Sharingan to tame Kurama).
This would mean they were swallowed before Kurama was ever sealed inside any Uzumaki.

[image: Chapter 529, page 3]
<sub>Chapter 529, page 3</sub>

> Now, we also know that the Kin/Gin brothers were at the same time as the second Hokage, Tobirama. Given that they were the ones who killed him.

Although this is true, *I think* Tobirama and Hashirama are almost the same age, which would mean Kinkaku and Ginkaku's age is somewhere around both Senju brothers.

---

From what I understand, the timeline would go something like this (not sure about how much time between each "step"):

- Founding of Konoha;
- Founding of Kumo;
- Kinkaku and Ginkaku get swallowed, when sent to capture Kurama;
- Madara deserts and attacks Konoha, using Kurama;
- Hashirama wins the battle, and Uzumaki Mito seals Kuruma inside of her.

Comment: But then again, the cloud didn't exist before the leaf, so how does that work out?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Added a timeline, which I think makes sense, but I may be missing something.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha The only thing that really bothers me is the consistent use (either by Kishimoto or by the people who translate chapters) of expressions like "a long time before/after event x", which makes the timeline seem a lot longer than it actually is.